# How to verify how long the JS scripts are taking to run in a website?

Tags: javascript, web-applications

I joined a project that is developing a website. 
We have a main page, but this page is taking extremely long to load and we suspect that one of our scripts is not running correctly (maybe executing too many times or a extremely large loop).
Is there any software that can measure how long each script is taking to run?

Thanks!

Comment: Google Chrome has developer tools which can profile the JS in a page, as well as many other things.

Comment: Developer Tools are built into many browsers.

Comment: All browsers support this in some way. Chrome and Safari it is built in. Firefox offers Firebug. (By all browsers, I mean all browsers worth using)

Comment: I disagree with the close vote.. valid question. only thing it shows lack of is debugging ability and web development experience.

Comment: Ok guys, thanks for your effort. I knew about firebug but I didn´t know about this abilitym tks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bring up the developer tools in Chrome (Tools | Developer Tools) there's an "Audits" tab that you can use to do a quick check of your page (there should be a "Reload Page and Audit on Load" option to check before you click on "Run". It will give you some suggestions as to issues it finds on your page. There are other, more extensive ways to check, but this is a very quick "audit" you can perform.

Comment: Just marked as answered. Both answers were great, but this one was more detailed. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using a [Profiler](http://getfirebug.com/javascript)? FireBug is good.